# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce

this error is occurring ??
Here is my code.Where i mistook ?

```
public PageReference find() 
{         
    for(Account c : [SELECT BillingCountry, Industry, (SELECT Id, Name,Amount , StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE BillingCountry = 'USA'])
    {
            ResultWrapper result = new ResultWrapper(c,c.Opportunities);
            lstResultWrapper.add(result);                
            system.debug('=============lstResultWrapper================='+lstResultWrapper);

    }

    return null;
}     

public class ResultWrapper{

    public Account account {get;set;}
    public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}

    public ResultWrapper(Account acc,Opportunity opt)
    {
        this.account = acc;
        this.opportunity = opt;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which line is throwing the NullPointerException?

Comment: @jonnybro lstResultWrapper.add(result);    this line

Comment: Where is lstResultWrapper instantiated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you have a type mismatch

`c.Opportunities` is of type `List<Opportunity>`, but your constructor uses just one opportunity: public ResultWrapper(Account acc,Opportunity opt)

Also, add lstResultWrapper = new List() before your loop.

Comment: its works.But now the problem is i cant able show that on the datatable

Comment: Moin, do me a favor, then. Mark this question as accepted and open a new one with your datatable problem (include VF code, please). I'll go in there and help you as well.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113942/unknown-property-search-resultwrapper-account-markup pls visite this question